# Will Netlogo's BehaviorSpace run any quicker if I disable plots?

Tags: netlogo

If I remove plots from the interface screen in Netlogo, will BehaviorSpace run any quicker?

Answer (score 1):

In a typical model, `go` might contain something like `ask turtles [ fd 1 ]` and your plot might have something like `plot count turtles`. Plotting a point is cheap, comparable in cost to a single agent performing a simple operation. So if you have 100 turtles, then your model is spending about 99% of its time simulating, and only 1% of its time plotting. So removing the plot would have only a negligible effect.

So, the answer to your question is: probably not. I would expect almost any model would see no speedup, or only a negligible speedup.

I say "almost any" because it depends on what your model does every tick. If your `go` procedure does very little computation, and if you do a relatively expensive computation in one of your plots, then removing that plot could remove a big speedup. But I would expect models answering to this description to be quite rare.

Redrawing a plot on the screen does take some additional time, on top of what it costs to record that a point has been plotted, but I assume you've already noticed that BehaviorSpace's "Running Experiment" dialog has a checkbox where you can turn that off.